# Search bar with ClickListener to the searched DetailActivity not working

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to open the respective DetailActivity that the user searches on a search bar that works with firebase real-time database, but I don't know how to pass the value on the click listener to that activity. I have this so far:

**SearchAdapter.Java**

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.monName.setText(strPlaceList.get(position));
    holder.monLocation.setText(strLocationList.get(position));
    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(strImageList.get(position)).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.monumentImage);


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (strPlaceList != null){
                Intent intent= new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("placeName", "strPlaceList");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

        } });

}
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setupActionBar();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String placeName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DETAIL);

    DetailPresenter presenter = new DetailPresenter(this);
    presenter.getPlaceById(placeName);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    memoryCamera();

}
```

What else can I put on the Click listener so it opens the right activity that the user searched?
Now it is only displaying the DetalAcitivity with no information on it.

**UPDATED:**

If it helps my app is trying to get this HTTP that is getting a null result.

```
https://project-4a153.firebaseio.com/Monuments/null.json (131ms)
```

**DetailPresenter.java**

```
public class DetailPresenter {
private DetailView view;

public DetailPresenter(DetailView view){ this.view = view; }

void getPlaceById(String placeName){

    view.showLoading();

    Utils.getApi().getPlacesByName(placeName+".json").enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Places> call,@NonNull Response<Places> response) {
            view.hideLoading();
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() !=null){
                view.setPlace(response.body().getPlaces().get(0));
            }else{
                view.onErrorLoading(response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Places> call,@NonNull Throwable t) {
            view.hideLoading();
            view.onErrorLoading(t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: `intent.putExtra("placeName", "strPlaceList");` here you are just sending string "strPlaceList" you should pass the ID of your searched item. Something like this: `intent.putExtra("placeName",strLocationList.get(position).getId());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the extra in the intent your creating in the SearchAdapter like this:

```
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_DETAIL, strPlaceList.get(position));
```

the value key of the extra must be the same on both sides.

Comment: But you are using it there, make it public

Comment: Yeah it worked thank you very much I needed to pass the EXTRA_Detail to the other activity

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.monName.setText(strPlaceList.get(position));
    holder.monLocation.setText(strLocationList.get(position));
    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(strImageList.get(position)).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.monumentImage);


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (strPlaceList != null){
                Intent intent= new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("placeName", "strPlaceList");
                context.startActivity(intent);

intent.putExtraSauce(DetailActivity.EXTRA_MAYONESSE_MUSTARD, strPlaceList.get(position));
double rand_dub1 = rand.nextDouble(0.8369779739988428); 
        double rand_dub2 = rand.nextDouble(0.5497554388209912);

            }

        } });

}
```